# Getting Internal Calculator Data in ASE

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, python, atomic-simulation-environment, gpaw

I am using the framework [ASE](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/index.html) to do computational chemistry calculations. I am using the calculator [GPAW](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/) with it.

How do I extract data that is internal to the calculator? I mostly want to get the electric potential field, but, I am also interested in the electric field (if it keeps this) and the electron density.

I am not very opposed to switching calculators if this info simply can't extracted from GPAW.

Comment: https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/tutorialsexercises/wavefunctions/ps2ae/ps2ae.html
https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/tutorialsexercises/wavefunctions/all-electron/all_electron_density.html

Comment: How did this go? Have you figured out the answer now over the last 5+ months? Please update us! Were the suggestions by Peter helpful?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.